# Want an Android job only shows one job forever. Is this the perfect job for me :P?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I keep seeing the same ad of: ***Want an Android job?***. It is not very nice that I only see one company in like forever. This might be the only job available in my region, but maybe I am interested in jobs a little outside my region? I am definitely not interested in this job, as I am seeing it for half a year now and I still haven't reacted to it.

[image: booking.com job]

Comment: It's a sign they really want you. They paid top dollar to show this to you every day.

Comment: But how can you pass up a coffeebar and daily catered lunch?

Comment: Now i feel silly, I clicked learn more and sadly the screen shot did not tell me more.

Comment: I think you can downvote the job...

Comment: That's definitely not intentional. There's a test going on with single-job ads, but you should still see a bit of a variety. We'll see if we can figure out what's going on there.

Comment: They offer "commuting costs"? You have to pay them to commute?

Comment: An equally annoying "bug" is when you apply for a job via one of these links (because like you, I kept seeing the same one everyday) but the job posting doesn't exist on the company's site anymore. "The position has been filled", it says. No big deal; report the situation to SO and they email you back saying they'll take it down. Yet every day, for the next 5 weeks, you still see that same job posting for a position that the company isn't hiring for anymore. This occurrence has been happening between 3 different jobs- all filled, all being rotated to me at least once a day.

Comment: @8protons: Sounds like a bug you should report separately.

Comment: @BretCopeland, I can confirm that this is happening on more then just this guys account as well. While I get a little more variety then this guy, mine tends to cycle in just one at a company called ForeUP (which is for a UI designer role (I'm a programmer... so it's not even right...)) about 85% of the time.

Comment: "Every morning when I wake up I look in the mirror and Ask Myself _Do I Want to do what I am about to do today? and Everytime the answer is NO, I Know I Need to change something_" - Steve Jobs

Comment: I still think this is an annoying ad, woke up with it today again. Maybe I should just take a tattoo of a booking.com ad and just learn to live with it :P.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response (long weekend).

Normally, we impose a scoring penalty on jobs you've seen more than ten times. So the more times you've seen a particular job, the less likely you are to see it the next day.

That should usually take care of this sort of thing, but we uncovered a bug today in the process which tracks view counts. It was silently failing in a number of circumstances. We're going to backfill it tomorrow, and hopefully you'll get a bit more variety after that.

It's really not our intention to show you the same thing constantly, so I appreciate you pointing this out. Sorry for the annoyance.

Comment: It seems to work now :). Thanks for your answer and fix.